# How to add value labels to bars in ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I do not know how to add value labels in the middle of bars or on top of them in ggplot. My codes:
df <- data.frame(Player = c("Duncan Robinson", "Joe Harris", "Bojan Bogdanovic", "Damian Lillard",
"Khris Middleton", "mean"), EFG = c(66,61,58,58,58,50))
ggplot(data = df)+
geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Player, y = EFG),
stat = "identity", fill = 'cadetblue4') +
theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BK1iF.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65471457/7547327

Answer (score 0):

You can use `geom_text()`:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data = df)+ 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Player, y = EFG),
           stat = "identity", fill = 'cadetblue4') +
  geom_text(aes(x = Player, y = EFG,label=EFG),vjust=-0.25)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "bold"))
```

Output:

[image]